# Search function with multiple data type in C binary search tree

Tags: c, recursion, search, binary-search-tree, function-definition

I have a BST with id as a key as follows:

```
struct node
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;
};
```

Here is the code to search an id:

```
struct node* search(struct node *root, int x)
{
    if(root==NULL || root->id==x)
        return root;
    else if(x>root->id)
        return search(root->right, x);
    else
        return search(root->left,x);
}
```

But what if I want to search for a name? Is it possible? Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: You can have a common interface/function for searching like `struct node* bst_search (struct node *root, struct node* snode, int stype)` where `stype` tells which field to use & `snode` will have that field filled before call. You've to write individual search function based on `stype` & call them accordingly inside `bst_search ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the binary tree is ordered based on the key `int id` then you need to traverse all nodes of the tree to find a node with the specified name using the string function `strcmp`.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

struct node* search(struct node *root, const char *name )
{
    if(root==NULL || strcmp( root->name, name ) == 0 )
    {
        return root;
    }
    else 
    {
        struct node *target = search(root->left, name);
        return target != NULL ? target : search(root->right, name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse it is possible. You can use **strcmp** or any other function of your own for that. However the BST is created on the key **id** so you aren't going to benefit from the reduced search complexity which BST provides.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this issue before, I ended up rewriting my own implementation of BS alongside some improvements.
so what I did was generating a specific number(token) for each word (basically like hashing but with numbers), and whenever I wanna search for a word, it gets transformed to numerical tokens then use the BS algorithm normally.

### let's say the hashing algorithm works this way

- Every letter will have a pre-defined value according to its alphabetical order `A->1`  `B->1`...
- The letters order in the word plays a role for example the word `yap` cannot be the same as `pay` so what we can do is having a value `i = 1` so whenever we tokenize one letter we add that token to `i` so next letter's token we'll be raised to the power of `i` or something similar
- We also have to put in count ponctuations

```c
#include <math.h>
...
/* 
---------------------- NOTE ----------------------
 YOU PROBABLY WILL NEED TO IMPLEMENT A HASHMAP
 TO STORE THE ALPHABET LETTERS PRE-DEFINED VALUE,
 I'LL ASSUME THAT IT ALREADY EXISTS AND I WILL
 USE THIS METHOD TO GRAB THE VALUE
 get_value(hashmap,value);
 I'LL ALSO ASSUME THAT EVERY VALUE THE METHOD
 ABOVE RETURN EXISTS IN THE HASHMAP
-------------------------------------------------
*/
struct AlphabetOrderHashMap* hashmap = new_alphabet_order_hashmap();
int hash(char* word){
  int token = 0;
  int prev_letter_token = 1; // to address the letter order in the word
  for(int i =0;i < strlen(word);i++){
    prev_letter_token = hashletter(word[i],prev_letter_token);
    token +=  prev_letter_token
  }
  return token;

}
int hashletter(char letter,int i){
  int token = 0;
  token += (int)(pow(get_value(hashmap,letter),i) / (int)letter)
  return token;
}
...
```

and then I believe you can work it out from here. so instead of putting the word in the tree as char[], using the token will be better.

**you can also replace the id by the token so you'll only have to search once**